# spring batch: required a bean named 'dataSource' that could not be found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-3

I am upgrading spring boot from version 2.6.6 to 3.1.3.

I did the required JobRepository related modifications by referring [this sof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76294448/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-org-springframework-batch-core-configuration-a) post.

Everything seems to be going well but then I am facing below error -

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of method stepOne in com.mycompany.retail.esl.data_manager_job.product_publisher_job.ProductPublisherJob required a bean named 'dataSource' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("PRODUCT_PUBLISHER_JOB_STEP_ONE")


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'dataSource' in your configuration.
```

My step builder and job builder code is as below -

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductPublisherJob {

  private static final int DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE = 25;
  public static final String JOB_NAME = JobName.PRODUCT_PUBLISHER_JOB;

  @Bean(ProductPublisherJob.JOB_NAME)
  public Job job(
      @Qualifier(ProductPublisherJob.JOB_NAME + "_STEP_ONE") Step stepOne,
      JobRepository jobRepository,
      JobExecutionListener jobExecutionListener,
      @Qualifier("ArticleFlatFilePublisher") ArticleFlatFilePublisher articleFlatFilePublisher
  ) {
    return new JobBuilder(ProductPublisherJob.JOB_NAME, jobRepository)
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .flow(stepOne)
        .end()
        .listener(jobExecutionListener)
        .listener(articleFlatFilePublisher)
        .build();
  }

  @Bean(ProductPublisherJob.JOB_NAME + "_STEP_ONE")
  public Step stepOne(
      @Qualifier("ProductPublisherJobPageReader") ProductPublisherJobPageReader pageReader,
      JobRepository jobRepository,
      @Qualifier("ProductItemProcessor") ProductItemProcessor itemProcessor,
      @Qualifier("ArticleFlatFileWriter") ArticleFlatFileWriter itemWriter
  ) {
    return new StepBuilder(ProductPublisherJob.JOB_NAME + "_ONE", jobRepository)
        .<Product, Article>chunk(DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE)
        .reader(pageReader)
        .processor(itemProcessor)
        .writer(itemWriter)
        .build();
  }
}
```

I do have the required datasource props defined in application.properties and further it was all working well in spring boot 2.6.6.
Any suggestions on how to fix this. Any help will be greatly appreciated as this is a prod blocker for me.

**EDIT 1 - regrading the required data source bean**

I have below in application.properties

```
spring.batch.datasource.driver-class-name = org.h2.Driver
spring.batch.datasource.password = sa
spring.batch.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;
spring.batch.datasource.username = sa
```

and in build.gradle i have -

```
implementation "com.h2database:h2:2.2.224"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch"
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
```

IS THERE ANYTHING MORE I HAVE TO DO TO GET THE DATASOURCE BEAN IN TO APPLICATION CONTEXT.

**EDIT 2 - added datasource bean explicitly.**
I explicitly added below bean definition in to the configuration class.

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
  DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create(
  dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
  dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
  dataSourceBuilder.username("SA");
  dataSourceBuilder.password("");
  return dataSourceBuilder.build();
}
```

It suggested:

> Consider defining a bean named 'transactionManager' in your
> configuration.

so I added -

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
  return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
}
```

But now it's giving another error still related to transactionManager -

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'PRODUCT_PUBLISHER_JOB' defined in class
> path resource
> [com/wayfair/retail/esl/data_manager_job/product_publisher_job/ProductPublisherJob.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'job' parameter 0:
> Error creating bean with name 'PRODUCT_PUBLISHER_JOB_STEP_ONE' defined
> in class path resource
> [com/wayfair/retail/esl/data_manager_job/product_publisher_job/ProductPublisherJob.class]:
> Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.Step]: Factory
> method 'stepOne' threw exception with message:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: A transaction manager must be
> provided

**I am providing transaction manager explicitly, still why does it complain.**

**Edit 3 - Itemwriter code as requested by Gurkan.**

```
@Component("ArticleFlatFileWriter")
public class ArticleFlatFileWriter extends FlatFileItemWriter<Article> {

  private final ArticleMapper articleMapper;
  ArticleFlatFileWriter(
      @Value("${app.storage.localFile}") String file,
      @Value("${app.storage.file.csv.header}") Boolean includeHeader,
      @Qualifier("ArticleLineAggregator") ArticleLineAggregator lineAggregator,
      ArticleMapper articleMapper
  ) {
    super();

    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(includeHeader)) {
      this.setHeaderCallback(this::headerCallback);
    }

    var fileSystemResource = new FileSystemResource(file);

    this.setAppendAllowed(true);
    this.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    this.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);
    this.setResource(fileSystemResource);
    this.setShouldDeleteIfExists(true);
    this.articleMapper = articleMapper;
  }

  private void headerCallback(Writer writer) throws IOException {
    writer.write(String.join(ArticleLineTokenizer.DEFAULT_DELIMITER, this.articleMapper.getHeaderNames()));
  }

  protected boolean isAppendAllowed() {
    return this.append;
  }
}
```

**Edit 4 -**
After updating the StepBuilder code to below (like also suggested by skillup), Transaction manager issue is solved but am facing `Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': JPA metamodel must not be empty`. [I have posted a new question for this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77274742/error-creating-bean-with-name-jpamappingcontext-jpa-metamodel-must-not-be-emp)

```
@Bean(UpdateAssignedProductsJob.JOB_NAME + "_STEP_ONE")
public Step stepOne(
    @Qualifier("UpdateAssignedProductsJobPagedItemReader") UpdateAssignedProductsJobPagedItemReader itemReader,
    JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
    @Qualifier("ProductItemProcessor") ProductItemProcessor itemProcessor,
    @Qualifier("ArticleFlatFileWriter") ArticleFlatFileWriter itemWriter
) {
   return new StepBuilder(UpdateAssignedProductsJob.JOB_NAME + "_STEP_ONE", jobRepository)
      .<Product, Article>chunk(DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE, transactionManager)
      .reader(itemReader)
      .processor(itemProcessor)
      .writer(itemWriter)
      .build();
}
```

Comment: Spring Batch 5 requires a datasource to be present. Apparently it isn't in your code,. All the steps needed for the mgiration are in the Spring Batch 5 migration guide -> https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#major-changes

Comment: @M.Deinum - please see my `edit 1` and let me know if I have to add anything more to get the datasource bean in to application context.

Comment: For H2 you don't need any additional configuration. Also make sure that you aren't excluding the auto configuration for the datasource.YOur second edit adds a bean named `getDataSource` the error explicitly asks for a bean named `dataSource`, rename your method. But it shouldn't be needed anyway.

Comment: Can you put Itemwriter as well because you may need datasource there in step1.

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez please see edit 3

Comment: @M.Deinum - got your point regarding `getDataSource`. Corrected it. Plz see **Edit - 2** again.  You said - `Also make sure that you aren't excluding the auto configuration for the datasource`. How can i verify / check this that I am not excluding auto configuration for data source.

Comment: @M.Deinum - have checked the code, i did NOT find anything like `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})` etc. Anywhere else also I should check.

Comment: You should pass in the transaction manager into your step method and pass it to the definition (that is what the error is telling you.

Comment: @M.Deinum/ +1.  i added this to StepBuilder `.transactionManager(transactionManager())`. Still I am getting same error.

Comment: Plese include the full stacktraced (and use code formatting not a quote as now it is unreadable). That being said you have read [the migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#major-changes) on what to change? As I strongly get the feeling you are doing trail and error and use google instead. More specifically [this part of the guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#infrastructure-beans-configuration-with-enablebatchprocessing) which explains in detail what to do.

Comment: I see that transaction manager is missing in this case. "transaction manager must be provided". If there is a dependency then it has to be defined automatically. Especially spring data dependency.

Comment: By default spring automatically defines with auto configuration when necessary dependency presents

Comment: In the item writer you do not use database operations so it is not useful for solving this problem

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez - this issue is solved. Now I am stuck with new issue - [JPA metamodel must not be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77274742/error-creating-bean-with-name-jpamappingcontext-jpa-metamodel-must-not-be-emp)

Comment: @M.Deinum - this issue is solved. Now I am stuck with new issue - [JPA metamodel must not be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77274742/error-creating-bean-with-name-jpamappingcontext-jpa-metamodel-must-not-be-emp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace the code of your step like this :

```
  @Bean(ProductPublisherJob.JOB_NAME + "_STEP_ONE")
  public Step stepOne( JobRepository jobRepository,PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
      @Qualifier("ProductPublisherJobPageReader") ProductPublisherJobPageReader pageReader,
      @Qualifier("ProductItemProcessor") ProductItemProcessor itemProcessor,
      @Qualifier("ArticleFlatFileWriter") ArticleFlatFileWriter itemWriter
  ) {
    return new StepBuilder(ProductPublisherJob.JOB_NAME + "_ONE", jobRepository)
        .<Product, Article>chunk(DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE, transactionManager)
        .reader(pageReader)
        .processor(itemProcessor)
        .writer(itemWriter)
        .build();
  }
```